# Change advanced options of a collector?

Tags: surveymonkey

SURVEY MONKEY

You can create a weblink collector by the API (create_collector).
Is there also a possibility to change the advanced options of the collector (ex. Responses Per Computer) by the API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, create_collector does not offer any options beyond 'name', 'thank_you_message' and 'redirect_url'.